# Unable to get Mapbox leaflet-omnivore to load markers from .csv

Tags: javascript, csv, mapbox, leaflet

I'm using the Mapbox.js API to build a really simple web map using a .csv file to place markers with tooltips.  I'm trying to use the suggested [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) library to easily parse the csv and place the markers.  Using [this example guide](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv/) I have been unable to get omnivore to place any markers at all.  I've also noticed that just importing the library adds considerable load time to the map with the script:

```
<script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.0.1/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>
```

Here is (some) of the .csv I'm trying to place:

```
Name,latitude,longitude,Sport,Contact,Website,Location
Oregon Avenue Octopi,39.915048,-75.170185,Softball,,www.octopisoftball.org,"Marconi Plaza Philadelphia PA 19148"
West Philly Waste,39.943065,-75.215689,Softball,,,"Kingsessing Rec Center Philadelphia PA 19143"
Pittsburgh Pounders,40.466298,-79.961581,Baseball,,,"Arsenal Park Pittsburgh PA 15201"
```

I've tried variations on the snippets:

```
omnivore.csv('/data/teams.csv').addTo(map);
```

and

```
omnivore.csv('/data/teams.csv', latfield:'lat', lonfield:'lng', delimiter:',').addTo(map);
```

My csv is in a proper location and should be able to be read.  The obvious question is whether this is a problem with my code or with omnivore.

I have had success inputting the markers individually but would much rather use a csv for easy adding and editing by multiple people.  I'm also open to suggestions outside of omnivore if anyone has any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the working snippet I've used, and everything works ok:

```
omnivore.csv('teams.csv').addTo(map);
```

However, you don't need to rush into changing the code, because, in your case, any change goes wrong as long as you load your file using the **file protocol**:

[image]

instead of loading the file from a web server, using the **http protocol**:

[image]

In my case, I use the XAMPP solution stack package, that installs everything I need to host web pages.

Therefore, I've created a folder in the `htdocs` folder, and I've putted the `html` and the `csv` files inside:

[image]

Running on a web server, you'll see that `leaflet-omnivore.min.js` is loading very quick, under 100 ms!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's going to be a bit before I can try this out on my own server, but it seems like it should be exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue than you, and then realize that it was a problem on the data. In order to log those errors on the console, you have to put:

```
omnivore.csv('your_file.csv', null, L.mapbox.featureLayer()).addTo(map)
  .on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And it will tell you which line is not working, such as an invalid lat or long. Hope this helps!